# Did Jesus say "Lord" or "Jehovah / Yahweh" when he spoke to Satan as to who is to be worship at Luke 4:8?

Tags: names-of-god, attributes-of-god

In Luke 4:8, many Bible translations use Lord as the word spoken to Satan as the one worthy of worship. Those words are a direct quote by Jesus from the Old Testament that clearly indicated 'Yahweh' or 'Jehovah'. There is no Adonay or the like in the Hebrew text sourced. So regardless of whatever traditions Jewish scribes or other bible translators have, Jesus will never be affected and will stay truthful.

> Luke 4:8 - καὶ ἀποκριθεὶς ὁ Ἰησοῦς εἶπεν αὐτῷ Γέγραπται Κύριον τὸν
> θεόν σου προσκυνήσεις καὶ αὐτῷ μόνῳ λατρεύσεις. = But Jesus answered,
> “It is written: ‘Worship the Lord your God and serve Him only.’ ”

Comment: Deuteronomy 6:13  [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/deuteronomy/6-13.htm) reads :- 'your God Yahweh'. That is to say your _Elohim_, Jehovah.

Comment: Welcome to the group. Question: You imply that Jesus would not be affected by Jewish tradition. What would you  make of his statement of Mt. 23:2 “The scribes and the Pharisees sit on Moses’ seat; 3 so practice and observe whatever they tell you."

Answer (score 3):

The New Testament was written in koine Greek, so we can only answer according to what was written. Nobody can tell you whether the spoken words of Jesus on that occasion were Lord, or Yahweh. (Given that 'Jehovah' is an English transliteration, Jesus would never have been heard voicing 'Jehovah'. I don't know the earliest use of Yahweh, but apparently by 1270 Dominican Catholic Raymundus Martini in his book 'Pugeo Fidei' did write "Yohoua". From that came 'Jehovah' in English.)

The point in question is what basis would there be in the Deuteronomy 6:16 text Jesus quoted for him saying Yahweh? Given that the Hebrew text has the Tetragram, translators like Robert Young put ***'Jehovah'*** in his 1862 translation. But when he came to Luke 4:8, Robert Young had Jesus saying, "Thou shalt bow before ***the Lord thy God,*** and Him only shalt thou serve." Why? Because he was now working from the Greek text.

There are some Greek NT texts that were translated into Hebrew, so the Tetragram would appear, which English translators might then render as'Jehovah' (such as at Luke 4:8). They are referred to as the 'J' MSS in NWT editions of the NT. Greek texts all have 'Lord'. Now, if we were to grant that it would be reasonable for Jesus to say 'Yahweh your God', a problem arises due to the vast preponderances of the Greek word 'Kyrios' (Lord) applying to Jesus, and not Jehovah, in the New Testament. To maintain that Jesus said 'Yahweh', would imply an equality between YHWH (the Tetragram) and 'Kyrios', thus raising the matter of Jesus actually being equated with Jehovah when he is called 'Kyrios'.

Jesus is called Lord 406 times but Jehovah God is only called Lord infrequently in the New Testament. For instance, Jesus said

> "I publicly praise you, Father, Lord of heaven and earth... (Luke
> 10:21 N.W.T.)

A scholarly examination of the N.W.T. frequent use of Jehovah in its Greek Scriptures makes this point:

> "As a designated title, however, Kyrios (Lord) is customarily used for
> Jesus in the Christian Greek Scriptures. Just as Jehovah called
> himself by name in the Hebrew Scriptures, so he gave Jesus two titles
> in the Christian Greek Scriptures.   "Therefore let all the house of
> Israel know for a certainty that God made him both Lord (Kyrios) and
> Christ, this Jesus whom you impaled" (Acts 3:36 N.W.T.)
>
> "There is actually to us one God the Father... and there is one Lord
> (Kyrios) Jesus Christ... (1 Corinthians 8:6 N.W.T. See also Jude vs. 4
> & Ephesians 4:5.)
>
> The importance of the discovery that the Tetragrammaton was not used
> by the apostolic authors should be clear. In many passages, the
> presence of Kyrios (when the context is referring to Jesus) identifies
> Jesus with Jehovah as we have already seen at Revelation 1:8.
>
> "I am the Alpha and the Omega" says Kyrios God, "the One who is and
> who was and who is coming, the Almighty." *The Tetragrammaton and the Christian Greek Scriptures* p.184, second edition 1998, Word Resources Inc.
>
> "The writers [of the Christian Greek Scriptures] themselves
> *intentionally - and with the early church's full knowledge and approval* - used the title Kyrios (which frequently identified Jesus)
> in place of the Tetragrammaton. By doing this, they ascribed the
> attributes of Jehovah's name to Jesus... We cannot imagine that
> Jehovah would allow confusion between his divine name and the title of
> a mere created being without sufficient evidence to correct the error.
> On the other hand, what if the original writers did use Jesus' title
> in place of the Tetragrammaton? It was either the highest form of
> blasphemy or it was the strongest statement possible of the unique and
> total equality of Jesus with Jehovah." (*Ibid.* pp.143-4)

This means that although the Deuteronomy verse Jesus quoted had Yahweh, and perhaps Jesus said, "Yahweh your God", the fact remains that the Holy-Spirit-inspired writers of the Christian Greek Scriptures ***wrote*** Kyrios. ***Yes, the Luke 4:8 text applied Kyrios to the Father, and not the Son (which Jesus confirmed)***, but those who are keen to put Yahweh in the Greek Scriptures hundreds of times when it was never initially written even once, need to pause and waken up to how that would - time and again - identify Lord Jesus with Lord God.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I just want to point out a few things.  Raymundus Martini is generally credited as being the one to use vowels from _adonay_ and insert them between YHWH to come up with a reconstructed way to pronounce the Divine Name.  However, "Jehovah" is most certainly **_not_ ** the form he used in ''Pugeo Fidei'.  That form would have been "Yohoua".  It's also debated whether or not he was the first one to do something like this.  Secondly, I'd like to know a bit more about the late Greek text you mentioned: J 7-19.  I couldn't find anything about it with a casual search. Thx!

Comment: @Aleph-Gimel  Your clarifications greatly appreciated. The Greek MS that is supposed to say 'Jehovah' at Luke 4:8 (& vs. 12) is given as a reference in The Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures (published in 1969 by Watchtower Bible & Tract Soc. of N.Y., Inc.) On p.27 they say of their 'J' references, "Used principally with regard to the divine name Jehovah. The 21 different reference works are distinguished by a superior number after the letter, from 1 to 21." Then pp 28-30 of their Interlinear detail the ones they claim support their translation 'Jehovah' in their NWT Lk.4:

Comment: J7 Greek Scriptures in Hebrew. In 1599 Elias Hutter of Nuremburg translated all the Christian Greek Scriptures into Hebrew… forming a part of Hutter’s ‘Polyglott NT of 1599. A copy is found at the NT Public Library.” The other J numbers are detailed similarly. Works in 1639, 1800,1817, 1831, 1838, 1846, 1855, 1866 & 1877 are used, nearly all of which can be read at the NY Public Library. They are all Greek scriptures in Hebrew but not Greek texts in English. It smacks of desperation to use them to claim the NWT has support for putting 'Jehovah' into its Greek Scriptures.

Comment: Aha! Thank you for clarifying - I thought you were talking about an ms/original text and not a translation.  Anyways, the fact remains that Ramón Martí did not invent the  reconstructed divine name as "Jehovah".  I'm not singling you out here because many people repeat this as a fact when it's untrue.  I think the confusion comes from a much later edition (hundreds of years after Martí's death) of the same work using the form "Jehova".  Maybe you'd edit your answer to clarify?

Comment: And as far as using "Jehovah" in the body of the N.T. goes, I think that's a different issue (probably asked elsewhere here?).  But the current list of their "J" references for Luke 4:8 looks like this: J7-18, 22-24, 27-44, 46-49, 52, 54, 57, 59-61, 65, 66, 88, 90, 93-95, 98, 100-106, 113-118, 120, 122, 125, 127, 128, 130, 133, 136, 138, 141, 144-147, 149-151, 153, 154, 160, 161, 163-167, 172, 180, 185-187, 189, 200, 203, 209, 210, 212-214, 217, 222, 223, 227, 228, 231, 235, 237, 242-244, 250, 259, 262, 265, 268, 271, 273, 275, 278, 279, 283, 287, 290, 295-297, 300

Comment: @Aleph-Gimel  Have corrected my answer re. those points and am glad of your helpful insights. For clarity, there are no Greek MSS of the NT that have 'Jehovah' in them. There are only ones that have been translated into Hebrew that have the Tetragram where the Greek Kyrios was originally written. This means that there is no support for the NWT prolific use of 'Jehovah' in their NWT from any Greek MSS - the original language the NT was written in.

Comment: Cool - spot on revision, no problem!  Regarding the translation of the divine name in the NT - I'm not really for or against it.  I do find it interesting (but also debated) that Matthew's Gospel could have potentially been first penned in Hebrew instead of Greek.  He also has Jesus quoting this OT commandment in chapter 4 and verse 10.  I live in a dream world where a small part of me thinks that someday an autograph ms will be discovered hehe.

Answer (score 1):

By the time that Jesus spoke the words in question, Jews were probably no longer pronouncing the Name of God directly (YHWH in text, or Yahweh in speech). Indeed, the custom of not speaking the Name seems to be very ancient. According to the [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13483-shaddai):

> The pronunciation of the written Name was used only by the priests in
> the Temple when blessing the people (Num. vi. 22-27); outside the
> Temple they used the title "Adonai" (Soṭah vii. 6; p. 38a). The high
> priest mentioned the Name on Yom Kippur ten times (Tosef., Yoma, ii.;
> 39b).

Early rabbinical sources are quite clear on this matter:

> (God's Name) was known in the earliest rabbinical works simply as the
> Name; also as Shem ha-Meyuḥad ("the Extraordinary Name"; Sifre, Num.
> 143); as Shem ha-Meforash ("the Distinguished Name"; Yoma vi. 2); as
> Shem ben Arba' Otiyyot ("the Tetragrammaton" or "the Quadriliteral
> Name"; Ḳid. 71a); and as Yod He Waw He (spelling the letters of Yhwh).

**From the above we may conclude that the Greek Κύριον τὸν Θεόν (Kyrion ton Theon) translated as "the Lord your God," is an accurate translation of first century Jewish usage either in Hebrew or Aramaic. Most likely is that Jesus would say "Adonai" (the Lord) rather than YHWH.**

Comment: Granting the Jews stop pronouncing God's name, is there a law that forbids Gods name to be written, read studied and discussed? What about the scroll that Jesus read in Luke 4, did Jesus translate God’s name to LORD when he read that?

Comment: Deuteronomy 6:13  [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/deuteronomy/6-13.htm) reads :- 'your God Yahweh'. That is to say your _Elohim_, Jehovah.

Comment: True we have copies of tge greek but we also have xopies of tge ild hebrew text and on that text we uave the tetragrammaton on Deut. 6:13 and no adonay. The greek trnaslation turned oyt and the various english translations that relied on them made two very serious errors. One, it removed the personal name of  God Yahweh / Jehovah from the bible which a billion people of the planet are not aware of. And second, it follow a tradition of adding adonay or Lord  ecen though it is not present on the original hebrew being paraphrased and again without the billions of people knowing it.

Comment: @AlexBalilo your question is addressed  [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73564/where-are-jews-forbidden-to-speak-the-name-of-god). It's not explicit in the bible but rabbincal law made it so.

Comment: @NigelJ... You are right about Deut. of course, but IMO the question is whether Jesus, in conversation, even paraphrasing scripture, would literally quote the written text or respect the conventions  of 1st c. Judaism.  Since there is no evidence that refraining from pronouncing the Name was something Jesus objected to, I think it's likely that he would do what his fellows Jews did on this matter.

Comment: @DanFefferman The words of Jesus are _reported_ in Greek, whatever language he used at the time he spoke, Aramaic or Hebrew or Greek itself. Therefore we must go by the Koine reported and refer that to the Hebrew text in regard to our own understanding. There may be a hidden agenda to questioning the word 'Lord' because Thomas called Jesus 'my Lord and my God' (in Greek), Thus the matter of worship becomes a feature of the title.

Answer (score 1):

**This is what we know:**

In Luke 4:8, Jesus was paraphrasing the text of Deut 6:13 which says, "Fear the LORD your God, serve Him only, ..."

Note that the LORD in the text above is translating the Hebrew tetragrammaton, YHWH, the never-pronounced sacred name of God.  Indeed, by Jesus' time, the vowels had been lost and few even knew how to pronounce the name.  Well-trained scribes, when reading the texts, always said, "Adonai" (= "Lord") to avoid pronouncing the name.

**What we do not know**

We do not know whether Jesus had the conversation with Satan in Hebrew, Aramaic, or Greek.  The most likely is Aramaic, but this is quite uncertain.

Therefore, the question is moot.  We do not know because it has not been recorded.  All we have is the Greek text of Luke.  However, had it been important for us to know, it would have been recorded.

Therefore, the fact that this detail was not recorded means that it was not important and does not matter.

Comment: We know.  Jesus spoke the personal name of God and not adonay. Old hebrew texts that preceeds the greek and english translations shows the presence of  tetragrammaton  on various passage being quoted. Jesus knows the pronounciation and Jesus everytimr he read passages from tye hebrew text with the teteagrammaton will never add an imvented word nor follow the Jewish tradition of not speaking the name of his Father.

Comment: @DadzSays - can you quote even a single instance in favor of your un-Biblical assertion?  (Please do not invent un-factual material)

Comment: Can you specify which of the things i said is unbiblical, unfactual?

Comment: @DadzSays - that Jesus spoke the name YHWH as recorded in the NT - there is no such recorded saying of Jesus.  Above you said, "We know. Jesus spoke the personal name of God and not adonay".  Please list a single place where is occurred - but there is NOT one.

Comment: @DadzSays you first comment would not be so objectionable if you were to say "I believe" rather than "we know." The [general guideline](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) is "Answers are welcome to be diverse and must always explain the hermeneutical process, quoting Biblical texts and citing sources for facts." Yours is not a "answer" but a "comment" but following this guideline will be helpful.

Comment: Matt 4:10 - Then Yeshua said to him  Depart Satan for it is written, " You shall worship the LORD JEHOVAH  your God and him alone shall you serve ". 
The Original Aramaic New Testament in Plain English (An American Translation of the Aramaic New Testament), Glenn David Bauscher, Australia, 2012

Comment: I was with you up to "Therefore, the fact that this detail was not recorded means that it was not important and does not matter." The Bible is replete with unrecorded details which are, almost certainly in some cases, deliberately left up to inference, and they matter at least a little; some, probably, matter a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A corollary question would be this:

*Was Jesus speaking Hebrew, Aramaic, or Greek when addressing Satan in the wilderness?*

The answer to that is simple: We do not know.

What we know is that by the time of Christ, the Jews were no longer pronouncing God's name as they regarded it too sacred.  In response to a question asked of one my Hebrew teachers as to what God's name was in the New Testament, he responded:

> From the Hasmonian period, the ban on pronouncing God’s name
> developed, so Greek manuscripts came to be written with κυριος to
> reflect the Jewish tradition of not pronouncing God’s name. But older
> manuscripts of LXX have ΠΙΠΙ (which in Greek is “pi-pi”) but it
> approximates God’s name in form pretty well. As to NT, the situation
> is a bit more complex. If NT was written in Hebrew, we have no
> surviving manuscripts, so what it could have had is pure speculation.
> If it was originally written in Aramaic (and then translated to
> Greek), then מריא was probably used (as evidenced by Targum and
> Peshitta), and if the NT were originally written in Greek (as most
> scholars think), then maybe κυριος won out because it was already
> taboo to pronounce God’s name aloud by that time.

There seems to be no good reason why Jesus would have refrained from pronouncing the name of his own Father.  It may well be that the writers of the story chose to substitute the word "Lord" (Greek "κυριος") for this as they were recording the story.

We also know that the Jewish scribes regarded the name of God as so sacred that, once written, it could not be destroyed or thrown away as if it were common trash.  Any writing with God's name attached could only be retired to the *Genizah*--a designated location for the storage of worn out or flawed "sacred" manuscripts.

### Conclusion

As we do not know even the language which Jesus was speaking (for certainly he was multilingual), we cannot be certain as to which form of address he used for God.

Comment: @Bibliasia. Granting that " we do not know even the language which Jesus was speaking (for certainly he was multilingual), we cannot be certain as to which form of address he used for God." How did the septuagint and different translations came about if the original language or languages were not known?

Comment: @AlexBalilo In Jesus' time, the Jews were still using Hebrew, they were using Aramaic/Syriac, and they were using Greek.  On Jesus' cross, Pilate ordered the inscription to be in Hebrew, Latin, and Greek (see John 19:20)--and the text says many of the Jews read it because of this.  Greek was considered the more scholarly and universal language of the time, with Hebrew mostly being understood only among the Jews.  As the NT writers wrote for a wider audience, Greek was a natural choice.